# Does there exist a function $f$ with an isolated singularity at $0$ and such that $|f(z)| \sim \exp(1/|z|)$ near $z = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a function $f$ with an isolated singularity at $0$ and such that $|f(z)|\sim \exp(1/|z|)$ near
$z = 0$?

**My  attempt** : I think yes  here $$\exp(1/|z|)= 1+ \frac{1}{|z|} + \frac{1}{2!|z|^2} + \frac{1}{3!|z|^3} +\ldots= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{|z|^n}.$$

The principal part of $f(z)$ contains infinite number of term therefore $z=0$ is an isolated essential singularity of $f(z)$.

This implies that $|f(z)| \sim \exp(1/|z|)$ has essential singularity.

Am I right?

Comment: What is your $f$? Note that $f$ has to be analytic in a punctured neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: okss @Gary   actually  I've made a mistake.  I was thinking $f$ is not pole

Comment: $f$ is a function, it cannot be a pole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $|f(z)|$ behaves as $\exp\left(\frac1{|z|}\right)$ near $0$, then $\lim_{z\to0}|f(z)|=\infty$, and therefore $f$ has a pole at $0$. So, for some $n\in\Bbb N$ (the order of the pole), $\lim_{z\to0}|z|^n\exp\left(\frac1{|z|}\right)$ exists (in $(0,\infty)$). But that doesn't happen. In fact$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\lim_{z\to0}|z|^n\exp\left(\frac1{|z|}\right)=\infty.$$

Comment: sir i have some confusion  why $\lim_{z\to0}|z|^n\exp\left(\frac1{|z|}\right)=\infty.?$ I think it should be $\lim_{z\to0}|z|^n\exp\left(\frac1{|z|}\right)=\lim_{z\to0}|z|^n\lim_{z\to0}\exp\left(\frac1{|z|}\right)=0.\infty=0$

Comment: By that argument,$$1=\lim_{x\to\infty}1=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\frac1x=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=\infty\cdot0=0.$$

Comment: okss sir  that mean $ f(z) ∼\frac{1}{|z|^n}$ near $0$ ?  Am i right ?

Comment: If it has a pole of order $n$, yes (and this is about $|f(z)|$, not about $f(z)$).